# add data to M2M through models

Tags: django

I'm trying to make records for my database of a web-based course planning application in an institution. My concern is that of not being able to make recordings in the intermediary table resulting from the relation M2M in views.py but it works in shell in browser I have an **ValueError :The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.**

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner

                response = get_response(request)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

     ...
▶ Local vars
E:\PLACORESA\configuration\views.py in departemnent

                cursus = get_object_or_404(Cursus, libelle_cursus=cursus )

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in get_object_or_404

            return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get

            num = len(clone)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in __len__

            self._fetch_all()

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in _fetch_all

                self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in __iter__

            results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in execute_sql

                sql, params = self.as_sql()

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in as_sql

                    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in compile

                sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py in as_sql

                    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in compile

                sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py in as_sql

            rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py in process_rhs

                        'The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to '

     ...
▶ Local vars
```

**models.py**

```
class Departement(models.Model):
    code_departement=models.CharField("code du département", max_length=100, unique=True)
    libelle_departement=models.CharField("Libellé du département", max_length=100)
    faculte=models.ForeignKey("Faculte", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cursus=models.ManyToManyField("Cursus", through="AvoirCursus")   

class Cursus(models.Model):
    code_cursus=models.CharField("Code du cursus", max_length=10, unique=True)
    libelle_cursus=models.CharField("Libellé du cursus", max_length=100) 

class AvoirCursus(models.Model):
    cursus=models.ForeignKey("Cursus", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    departement=models.ForeignKey("Departement", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        f = forms.Departement_Form(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            dept = f.save(commit=False)
            code_departement = f.cleaned_data['code_departement'].upper()
            dept.code_departement = code_departement
            cursus = f.cleaned_data['cursus']
            dept.save()
            cursus = get_object_or_404(Cursus, libelle_cursus=cursus )

            AvoirCursus(departement=dept, cursus=cursus)

            return redirect('configuration:lister_departement')
```

Comment: Please, add your stacktrace

Comment: please Sir @Stargazer  what do you mean by my stacktrace? is't the part of the trace back error??

Comment: Yes, that is it

Comment: know traceback is available Sir

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that cursus object get works correctly?
Maybe cursus from form returns more than one value or string?

Also, try to add print(cursus) after get_or_404 and see whats inside.

And what exactly are you trying to do here?

> AvoirCursus(departement=dept, cursus=cursus)

Are you sure it's not supposed to be:

> AvoirCursus.objects.create(departement=dept, cursus=cursus)

?

It's hard to figure something out without stack trace.

Comment: Hi have try to print(cursus)  I don't have the response; I have print it with success in shell I have one objects. Secondly i have change  ** AvoirCursus(departement=dept, cursus=cursus)** to **AvoirCursus.objects.create(departement=dept, cursus=cursus) ** but not success I have put traceback of error please see it.

Comment: @GabinTEKAM try to replace cursus = get_object_or_404(Cursus, libelle_cursus=cursus ) with block:
try: Cursus.objects.get(libelle_cursus=cursus) except Exception as e: print(str(e))

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded to resolve my problème. The forms used in views is the generic form from models.py. when I've  print(cursus ) the result was a queryset containing selected items.To write in the intermediate database, I made the course of "cursus" to have the different objects.

```
**the views.py is:**
if f.is_valid():
            dept = f.save(commit=False)
            code_departement = f.cleaned_data['code_departement']
            dept.code_departement = code_departement
            print(code_departement)
            cursus = f.cleaned_data['cursus']
            dept.save()
            for i in cursus:
                AvoirCursus.objects.create(departement=dept, cursus=i)
```